# Sprintf in mips

Tags: mips, printf

So I am trying to create Sprintf in MIPS. The problem is, I am not sure how to do all the cases for %d, %c, etc.

So even if I do recognize the % how do I recognize the next character? I mean, so I have % in register $a3.
li $a3, '%'

However, I won't have enough registers for $d, %c, %b, etc.

How would I check for them all?

```
######################################################################
# spf-main.s
# 
# This is the main function that tests the sprintf function

# The "data" segment is a static memory area where we can 
# allocate and initialize memory for our program to use.
# This is separate from the stack or the heap, and the allocation
# cannot be changed once the program starts. The program can
# write data to this area, though.
    .data

# Note that the directives in this section will not be 
# translated into machine language. They are instructions 
# to the assembler, linker, and loader to set aside (and 
# initialize) space in the static memory area of the program. 
# The labels work like pointers-- by the time the code is 
# run, they will be replaced with appropriate addresses.

# For this program, we will allocate a buffer to hold the
# result of your sprintf function. The asciiz blocks will
# be initialized with null-terminated ASCII strings.

buffer: .space  20000           # 2000 bytes of empty space 
                    # starting at address 'buffer'

format: .asciiz "string: %s, unsigned dec: %u, hex: 0x%x, char: %c, dec: %d, bin: %b, percent: %%\n"
                    # null-terminated string of 
                    # ascii bytes.  Note that the 
                    # \n counts as one byte: a newline 
                    # character.
str:    .asciiz "thirty-nine"       # null-terminated string at
                    # address 'str'
chrs:   .asciiz " characters:\n"    # null-terminated string at 
                    # address 'chrs'
strpd:  .asciiz "%d"        # null-terminated string at 
strpc:  .asciiz "%c"        # null-terminated string at 
strpb:  .asciiz "%b"        # null-terminated string at     
strpu:  .asciiz "%u"        # null-terminated string at
strpx:  .asciiz "%x"        # null-terminated string at 
strpo:  .asciiz "%o"        # null-terminated string at 
strps:  .asciiz "%s"        # null-terminated string at 
strpp:  .asciiz "%%"        # null-terminated string at 
strpi:  .asciiz "%"     # null-terminated string at 



# The "text" of the program is the assembly code that will
# be run. This directive marks the beginning of our program's
# text segment.

    .text

# The sprintf procedure (really just a block that starts with the
# label 'sprintf') will be declared later.  This is like a function
# prototype in C.

    .globl sprintf

# The special label called "__start" marks the start point
# of execution. Later, the "done" pseudo-instruction will make
# the program terminate properly.   

main:
    addi    $sp,$sp,-36 # reserve stack space

    # $v0 = sprintf(buffer, format, str, 255, 255, 111, -255, -255)

    la  $a0,buffer  # arg 0 <- buffer
    la  $a1,format  # arg 1 <- format
    la  $a2,str     # arg 2 <- str

    addi    $a3,$0,255  # arg 3 <- 255
    sw  $a3,16($sp) # arg 4 <- 255

    addi    $t0,$0,111
    sw  $t0,20($sp) # arg 5 <- 111 ('o', as a character)

    addi    $t0,$0,-255
    sw  $t0,24($sp) # arg 6 <- -255

    addi    $t0,$0,255  
    sw  $t0,28($sp) # arg 7 <- 255

    sw  $ra,32($sp) # save return address
    jal sprintf     # $v0 = sprintf(...)

    # print the return value from sprintf using
    # putint()

    add $a0,$v0,$0  # $a0 <- $v0
    jal putint      # putint($a0)

    ## output the string 'chrs' then 'buffer' (which
    ## holds the output of sprintf)
    li  $v0, 4  
    la      $a0, chrs
    syscall
    #puts   chrs        # output string chrs

    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, buffer
    syscall
    #puts   buffer      # output string buffer

    addi    $sp,$sp,36  # restore stack
    li  $v0, 10     # terminate program
    syscall

# putint writes the number in $a0 to the console
# in decimal. It uses the special command
# putc to do the output.

# Note that putint, which is recursive, uses an abbreviated
# stack. putint was written very carefully to make sure it
# did not disturb the stack of any other functions. Fortunately,
# putint only calls itself and putc, so it is easy to prove
# that the optimization is safe. Still, we do not recommend 
# taking shortcuts like the ones used here.

# HINT: You should read and understand the body of putint,
# because you will be doing some similar conversions
# in your own code.

putint: addi    $sp,$sp,-8  # get 2 words of stack
    sw  $ra,0($sp)  # store return address

    # The number is printed as follows:
    # It is successively divided by the base (10) and the 
    # reminders are printed in the reverse order they were found
    # using recursion.

    remu    $t0,$a0,10  # $t0 <- $a0 % 10
    addi    $t0,$t0,'0' # $t0 += '0' ($t0 is now a digit character)
    divu    $a0,$a0,10  # $a0 /= 10
    beqz    $a0,onedig  # if( $a0 != 0 ) { 
    sw  $t0,4($sp)  #   save $t0 on our stack
    jal putint      #   putint() (putint will deliberately use and modify $a0)
    lw  $t0,4($sp)  #   restore $t0
                            # } 
onedig: move    $a0, $t0
    li  $v0, 11
    syscall         # putc #$t0
    #putc   $t0     # output the digit character $t0
    lw  $ra,0($sp)  # restore return address
    addi    $sp,$sp, 8  # restore stack
    jr  $ra     # return





    #sprintf!
#$a0 has the pointer to the buffer to be printed to
#$a1 has the pointer to the format string
#$a2 and $a3 have (possibly) the first two substitutions for the format string
#the rest are on the stack
#return the number of characters (ommitting the trailing '\0') put in the buffer

        .text

sprintf:
    addi $sp, $sp, -12
    sw $ra, 8($sp)
    sw $s1, 4($sp)
    sw $s2, 0($sp)







    li $a3, '%'     



        li      $s0, 0          # len = 1
        la      $s1, ($a1)        # s = str
test:
        lb      $s2, 0($s1)     # c = *s
        beqz    $s2, done       # if c == '\0', branch to "done"
     #   beq    $s2, $a3, percent

        addi    $s0, $s0, 1     # len = len + 1
        addi    $s1, $s1, 1     # s = s + 1
        j       test

percent:
     li $v0, 4    # print_string    
    la $a0, str 
    syscall



done:
     #   li      $v0, 1          # syscall code: print_int
     #   move    $a0, $s0
     #   syscall
       li      $v0, 11         # syscall code: print_char
        li      $a0, 10         # pass newline character
        syscall


        add $v0,$0, $s0
        lw $ra, 8($sp)
        lw $s1, 4($sp)
    lw $s2, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 12

        jr      $ra
```

Comment: You could take the sprintf implementation in C and machine translate it to MIPS assembly with a MIPS compiler so that you may see how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop to check for the next character inside the `sprintf` function. This loop should scan the next character, compare it to the list of available characters you'll be using and then branch off into the necessary function, which includes going back to the loop in case you get `%%`.